# Why the browsers confirm box (triggered by beforeunload event handler) only appears when I click onto the page?

Tags: javascript, web, frontend

I would like to display a confirm box and warn the user, before he leaves the page, especially during an HTTP request. To this end, I added an event listener to the window object within my react component.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleBeforeUnload);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleBeforeUnload);
  }

  handleBeforeUnload(e) {
    e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?';
  }
```

This snippet works and makes our life easier but there's one thing that piqued my curiosity.

I see the confirm box, only if I click onto the page after loading. 
It does not display the browsers native confirm box, although it triggers the handleBeforeUnload method.

Could someone explain, why window.onbeforeunload works only if I focus into the page?

Answer (score 0):

This is an intentional limitation. From MDN:

> Note: To combat unwanted pop-ups, browsers may not display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with, or may even not display them at all.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload